# How to identify unrepaired corrupted files through the log created by dism?

Tags: cmd.exe, logging, filesystem-corruption, dism

If by running the command " Dism /image:C:\ /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:D:\install.wim /LimitAccess
", dism fails to repair some system files, does it create a log and mention them in it?
How to identify unrepaired corrupted files through the created log?
In the log, under what title does it refer to these unrepaired damaged files?

Comment: That is most often an exercise in futility.  I restart after the repair and run DISM a second time if needed. Most often not.

Answer (score 1):

The log file is here by default: `C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log`

You can manually set a different location by adding `/LogPath:<path_to_log_file.log>`

And optionally include debug output with `/LogLevel:4`

See also: [DISM Global Options for Command-Line Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-global-options-for-command-line-syntax?view=windows-11#options)

Comment: Thank you for your guidance . How to identify unrepaired corrupted files through the created log? In the log, under what title does it refer to these unrepaired damaged files?

Comment: @SEPEHR It may change depending on the reason why it failed to repair (couldn't find source or couldn't write to destination for example). I would check for lines with `", Error "` or add `/LogLevel:1` to only log error messages, then see if any of those lines have file paths like `C:\Windows`.